# what is the best fastest approach in extracting images in a psd?

Tags: html, photoshop, psd

I have a psd web design and I am trying to extract is by going on the layer duplicating layer document is new then convert to smart object ctrl n to create new layer then paste then ctrl save.

It is so many steps. Is there any other better and faster way?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new service introduced into Adobe's Creative Cloud called "Extract" that should help you extract assets as well as other information from a PSD. To use it:

- Login to creative.adobe.com/files
- Upload the PSD
- Click on the Extract tab.
- Select an item to extract and choose a format: PNG, JPG or SVG.

This service in Adobe's Creative Cloud is free to all users. You just need a login. If you want to try it without a login, check out: http://www.adobe.com/go/extract_tweet1

Comment: Thanks @Vasudev I'll look into this. By the way does adobe id requires payments?

Comment: no it's free creating an adobe id.. but for application purchases we have to pay...